# Apache configuration - Why I get redirect loop?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, redirect, httpd.conf

I have Apache server and JBoos server with my application on my local computer.

This is my Apache configuration:

- httpd.conf

  ```
  ServerRoot "C:/opt/Apache"
  Listen 80

  LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
  LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
  LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
  LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
  #LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
  #LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
  #LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
  #LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
  #LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
  LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
  LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
  #LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
  #LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
  LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
  LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
  LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
  #LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
  LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
  LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
  #LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
  #LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
  LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
  #LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
  #LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
  #LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
  #LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
  #LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
  LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
  LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
  #LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
  #LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
  LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
  #LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
  #LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
  #LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
  #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
  LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
  #LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
  #LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
  LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
  #LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
  LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
  #LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
  #LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
  LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
  #LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
  #LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
  LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
  #LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
  LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
  LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
  LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
  LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
  LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
  #LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
  LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
  #LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
  #LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
  LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
  LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
  #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
  #LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
  #LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
  #LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
  #LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
  #LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
  #LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
  LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

  <IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
  <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>

  User daemon
  Group daemon

  </IfModule>
  </IfModule>


  ServerAdmin example@com
  DocumentRoot "C:/opt/Apache/htdocs"
  <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
  </Directory>

  <Directory "C:/opt/Apache/htdocs">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <IfModule dir_module>
      DirectoryIndex index.html
  </IfModule>

  <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
      Satisfy All
  </FilesMatch>

  ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
  LogLevel warn

  <IfModule log_config_module>
       LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
       LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
       <IfModule logio_module>
             LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
       </IfModule>
       CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule alias_module>
      ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/opt/Apache/cgi-bin/"
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule cgid_module>
   </IfModule>

   <Directory "C:/opt/Apache/cgi-bin">
       AllowOverride None
       Options None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   DefaultType text/plain

   <IfModule mime_module>
       TypesConfig conf/mime.types
       AddType application/x-compress .Z
       AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

   </IfModule>

   # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

   # Multi-language error messages
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

   # Fancy directory listings
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

   # Language settings
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

   # User home directories
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

   # Real-time info on requests and configuration
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

   # Virtual hosts
   Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

   # Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

   # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

   # Various default settings
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

   # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
   #Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

   <IfModule ssl_module>
        SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
        SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    </IfModule>
  ```
- httpd-vhosts.conf

  ```
      <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerName dev.example
         DocumentRoot "C:/opt/Apache/htdocs_dev.example"

          <Directory />
              Options FollowSymLinks
              AllowOverride None
              Allow from all
          </Directory>
          ProxyPreserveHost on
          ProxyPass /test-site1 !
          ProxyPass /test-site2 !

          ProxyPass / http://localhost:10080/
          ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:10080/

          ErrorLog "logs/dev.example-error.log"
          CustomLog "logs/dev.example-access.log" common
      </VirtualHost>

      <VirtualHost *:80>
          ServerName blog.dev.example
          DocumentRoot "C:/opt/Apache/htdocs_blog.dev.example"
          <Directory />
              Options FollowSymLinks
              AllowOverride None
              Allow from all
          </Directory>
          ProxyRequests off
      <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
      </Proxy>

      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.*$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^/author/([^/]+)$ /index/-/c/author/$1 [P,L]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.*$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^/tag/([^/]+)$ /index/-/c/tag/$1 [P,L]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.*$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /index/-/c/$1 [P,L]

      ProxyPreserveHost on
      ProxyPass /contact !
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:10080/

      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json

      ErrorLog "logs/blog.dev.example-error.log"
      CustomLog "logs/blog.dev.example-access.log" common
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

When I get to http://dev.example in browser everything is ok and I get home site of my app. But when I get to http://blog.dev.example I get error and information about redirect loop.

I think that I made some mistake in configuration. Do you see what can be wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
$ curl -v http://blog.dev.example >/dev/null
* Rebuilt URL to: http://blog.dev.example/
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to blog.dev.example (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: blog.dev.example
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 10:20:41 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1
< X-Powered-By: JSP/2.2
< Location: http://blog.dev.example/
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 216
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=gi821fxux6X2f2Si9kxsPtkK.undefined; Path=/
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
* Connection #0 to host blog.dev.example left intact`


$ curl -v http://blog.dev.example/ >/dev/null
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to blog.dev.example (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: blog.dev.example
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 10:32:02 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1
< X-Powered-By: JSP/2.2
< Location: http://blog.dev.example/
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 216
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9P-1TFJMCMJe0eJUP6cOa3FU.undefined; Path=/
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
* Connection #0 to host blog.dev.example left intact
```

Comment: please provide output of `curl -v http://blog.dev.example >/dev/null`

Comment: @Peter I get this: 
`$ curl -v http://blog.dev.example >/dev/null
* Rebuilt URL to: http://blog.dev.example/
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for blog.dev.example:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'blog.dev.example'
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'blog.dev.example'
`

Comment: in your example above, you have changed the real dns to blog.dev.example.com... to post that output, you'll have to put the real dns in there.

Comment: @Peter so what should I do?

Comment: rerun curl but instead of the fake dns name you gave serverfault "blog.dev.example", fill in the one that works on your dns setup.

Comment: @Peter sorry :) I see my gaffe:)
I post  real output in edit.

Comment: ok good. Now see `Location: http://blog.dev.example/` is what it wants you to go to next. It added a "/" on the end of the url  you gave, so it has changed. Now repeat curl with the new url, and make a note of each new "Location" header it gives you. Repeat that until you see that it is looping. Then we can use this information to follow the config file to see why it has this result.

Comment: @Peter As you can see in may last edit, if i send `curl -v http://blog.dev.example/ >/dev/null` I get output with `Location: http://blog.dev.example/`

Answer (score 0):

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:10080/
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /index/-/c/$1 [P,L]
```

I think the reason it doesn't redirect to `/index/-c/$1` is that the ProxyPass just redirects before hitting the RewriteRule. It always redirects regardless of the path, so it never proceeds to the RewriteRule.

To fix it, you have to move it after the RewriteRule.

Comment: I change expresion order, like in my last edit, but it doesn't resolve problem :(

Comment: I would expect that now it should first redirect the client to `/index/-/c/`, and then after that, it will invisibly go to `localhost:10080` which is no longer in this conf file. Is that what it does (test with curl again)?

Comment: Same situation like before: `curl -v http://blog.dev.example >/dev/null` get ouput with `Location: http://blog.dev.example/` and `curl -v http://blog.dev.example/ >/dev/null` get ouput with `Location: http://blog.dev.example/` too

Comment: well all I can suggest after that is just to try adding test code in your config, for example proxy (with RewriteRule instead of ProxyPass) to a static html page at the top of your config, and move that line down by one line each test until you find out which config line is relevant. Test without the localhost:100080 part too.